# Weird duplication/mistakes in command line when I copy and paste commands

Tags: macos, command-line, copy-paste

I have these following commands that work when I run them individually.

```
find ./temp -name "Keller, Whitney" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Keller, Whitney_73618848766720/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; find ./temp -name "Keller, Whitney" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Keller, Whitney_73618848766720/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; cp -Rn "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Keller, Whitney_73618848766720/Student_Documents" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Keller, Whitney_73618848766720/" ; 
find ./temp -name "Kim, Christina" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Christina_73618848766722/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; find ./temp -name "Kim, Christina" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Christina_73618848766722/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; cp -Rn "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Christina_73618848766722/Student_Documents" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Christina_73618848766722/" ; 
find ./temp -name "Kim, Daniel" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Daniel_73618848766721/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; find ./temp -name "Kim, Daniel" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Daniel_73618848766721/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; cp -Rn "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Daniel_73618848766721/Student_Documents" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Daniel_73618848766721/" ; 
find ./temp -name "Kim, Eunice" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Eunice_73618848767724/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; find ./temp -name "Kim, Eunice" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Eunice_73618848767724/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; cp -Rn "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Eunice_73618848767724/Student_Documents" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Eunice_73618848767724/" ; 
find ./temp -name "Kim, Rebecca" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Rebecca_73618848766723/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; find ./temp -name "Kim, Rebecca" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Rebecca_73618848766723/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; cp -Rn "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Rebecca_73618848766723/Student_Documents" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Rebecca_73618848766723/" ;
```

However, when I copy and paste all 5 of them into my command-line (highlighting all 5, command-C, command-V), the command line looks like this:

```
D-XXX-XX-XXX-XXX:renameFoldersProject oppeasnt$ find ./temp -name "Keller, Whitney" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Keller, Whitney_73618848766720/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; find ./temp -name "Keller, Whitney" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Keller, Whitney_73618848766720/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; cp -Rn "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Keller, Whitney_73618848766720/Student_Documents" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Keller, Whitney_73618848766720/" ; 
find ./temp -name "Kim, Christina" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Christina_73618848766722/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; find ./temp -name "Kim, Christina" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Christina_73618848766722/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; cp -Rn "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Christina_73618848766722/Student_Documents" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Christina_73618848766722/" ; 
find ./temp -name "Kim, Daniel" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Daniel_73618848766721/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; find ./temp -name "Kim, Daniel" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Daniel_73618848766721/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; D-XXX-XX-XXX-XXX:renameFoldersProject oppeasnt$ find ./temp -name "Kim, Christina" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Christina_73618848766722/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; find ./temp -name "Kim, Christina" -type d | while readt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Christina_73618848766722/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; cp -Rn "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Christina_73618848766722/Student_Documents" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Christina_73618848766722/" ; 
find ./temp -name "Kim, Daniel" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Daniel_73618848766721/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; find ./temp -name "Kim, Daniel" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Daniel_73618848766721/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; cpfiRn "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Daniel_73618848766721/Student_Documents" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Daniel_73618848766721/" ; 
find ./temp -name "Kim, Eunice" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Eunice_73618848767724/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; find ./temp -name "Kim, Eunice" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Eunice_73618848767724/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; cp -Rn "/Users/oppD-XXX-XX-XXX-XXX:renameFoldersProject oppeasnt$ find ./temp -name "Kim, Daniel" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Daniel_73618848766721/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; find ./temp -name "Kim, Daniel" -type d | w/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Daniel_73618848766721/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; cpfiRn "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Daniel_73618848766721/Student_Documents" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Daniel_73618848766721/" ; 
find ./temp -name "Kim, Eunice" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Eunice_73618848767724/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; find ./temp -name "Kim, Eunice" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Eunice_73618848767724/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; cp -Rn "/Users/oppeafind ./ktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Eunice_73618848767724/Student_Documents" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Eunice_73618848767724/" ; 
find ./temp -name "Kim, Rebecca" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Rebecca_73618848766723/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; find ./temp -name "Kim, Rebecca" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Rebecca_73618848766723/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; cp -Rn "/Users-bash: cpfiRn: command not found
D-XXX-XX-XXX-XXX:renameFoldersProject oppeasnt$ find ./temp -name "Kim, Eunice" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Eunice_73618848767724/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; find ./temp -name "Kim, Eunice" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Eunice_73618848767724/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; cp -Rn "/Users/oppeafind ./ktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Eunice_73618848767724/Student_Documents" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Eunice_73618848767724/" ; 
find ./temp -name "Kim, Rebecca" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Rebecca_73618848766723/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; find ./temp -name "Kim, Rebecca" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Rebecca_73618848766723/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; cp -Rn "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Rebecca_73618848766723/Student_Documents" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Rebecca_73618848766723/" ; cp: /Users/oppeafind ./ktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Eunice_73618848767724/Student_Documents: No such file or directory
D-XXX-XX-XXX-XXX:renameFoldersProject oppeasnt$ find ./temp -name "Kim, Rebecca" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Rebecca_73618848766723/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; find ./temp -name "Kim, Rebecca" -type d | while read path ; do (cp -Rn "$path/" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Rebecca_73618848766723/Student_Assignments/" ;) done ; cp -Rn "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Rebecca_73618848766723/Student_Documents" "/Users/oppeasnt/Desktop/RenameFoldersProject/Year_of_Entry_2016/Kim, Rebecca_73618848766723/" ;
```

You can see that some lines are repeated and much longer than in my original commands.

If you scroll more to the right you'll see things like

```
cp -Rn "/Users/oppD-XXX-XX-XXX-XXX:renameFoldersProject oppeasnt$
```

or

```
cp -Rn "/Users/oppeafind ./ktop/RenameFoldersProject/temp/2016/Kim, Eunice_73618848767724/Student_Documents
```

which look like collisions/overlap between different commands.

Why is this? How can I fix this?

Comment: get one `find` command to work at a time. Having multiple `find` cmds on the same cmd-line is crazy! AND use `set -vx` so you can see what is being executed and to show any values for env-vars that are included. Good luck.

Comment: There are two `find` commands on each line of the script you are running. Does that explain your output? (I think maybe it does). Good luck.

Comment: I think the shell is printing out the previous entry at the same time you are pasting in characters so they get intertwined.  If you want to avoid that you either need to turn off local echo or you could put all those lines into a file and source the file.  Either of those wouldn't show the commands being typed.  Or you could put all file on the same line by removing the carriage returns (assuming it isn't too long for your shell.  Putting the commands into a file and sourcing it is probably what I would do.

Comment: @shellter when I run each line individually it works perfectly, but if I copy more than about 2 at a time there’s a problem

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I’m sorry, I’m not very experienced. What does sourcing a file mean? Is there a tutorial I could follow? So far I’ve just been doing all my commands via Excel and command line

Comment: In a *nix shell, you can source a file/script by typing `source /path/to/script`. The source word can be also be reduced to a `.` char, so `. /path/to/script`, But I don't think is is necessary to use that feature of a *nix shell to run `/path/to/script` in another shell script. All you need is `/path/to/script`. If your script is well behaved, it will exit with a status code for OK, or error. If you have that, then you can write `if /path/to/script ; then echo script exited OK ; else echo error running script ; fi` You can do more inside the `if` and `else` blocks if need be. ...

Comment: (IMHO), you will reduce the confusion by putting each `find` command on a separate line. It is also quite possible that your `find` commands are generating error or warning messages. I would use a tmp log file to capture that info, but first zero out any previous runs with `> /tmp/myFindLog.txt; > /tmp/myFindErrs.txt`. Now append `>> /tmp/myFindLog.txt 2>>/tmp/myFindErrs.txt` at the end of each `find` command. You shouldn't get any ouput until the prompt is returned to you. Then `ls -l /tmp/myFind*`. look at any of those files where the size is not zero. ...

Comment: Now you can go thru and determine which line of script generated which output. If you need further help, edit your Q to include the relevant logfile information. You've taken on a complicated project, so you need to spend the time to analyze the system's feedback and understand the source of the problems.

Comment: And if you really want to understand your problem, you should delete any dirs and files that your previous runs created (but be careful you don't delete something else that was already there, take the time to be sure). Finally, I don't see why some `cp -Rn ...` commands are inside parentheses and others aren't. (Maybe that is right given conditions on your system that can't be seen from your Q, but I'd be surprised). Efficiency wize,  It hardly makes any difference, but  it may be affecting your results (or may all `cp -Rn...s`) need to be parenthesized? ....

Comment: As a worst case, run the `screen` command, run your problematic code , type the Ctr-D char (and enter) which should exit you from `screen`. It will tell you what file it has saved the transcript to, the post that file to file sharing site (pastebay?, many others). and add a link to it in your Q or here in comments addressed to me. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Honestly if you make that long thread an answer that would make a good answer. Thank you for your suggestions -- I will try them ASAP

Comment: @shellter  Since executing the file directly is easier, now you have to explain how to make the file executable.  Because that's what I was trying to avoid explaining.

Comment: marking a file as an executable is as easy as `chmod +x myScript` ; It will need a "she-bang" line as the first line, usually `#!/bin/bash` so the OS will now what interpreter to use for processing your script. IHTH. Good luck.

Comment: Oops, I meant, As a worst case run the `script` utility. First just type `script` at the cmd line, then run your command. When finished with all steps for your problem, type the Ctr-D char (and enter) which should exit you from `script`. (maybe you just type `exit`?).  It will tell you what file it has saved the transcript to. Post that file to file sharing site (pastebay?, many others). and add a link to it in your Q or here in comments addressed to me. Good luck.